# A Riddling Riddle

Tags: riddle

> 1. I am absolutely certain of my existence.
> 2. My ideal temperature range is between -40ºC and the temperature at which water freezes.
> 3. I can make positive improvements to myself.

**What am I?**

Hint:

> Each and every one of you is probably barking up the wrong tree.

Hint 2:

> The title of this puzzle has been updated and modified to be admittedly silly.

Enormously Bigly Hint 3:

> What do all of the clues and hints have in common with each other?

Comment: Should this have the `knowledge` tag?

Comment: @MikeQ - the knowledge tag is probably not a good fit here.

Comment: Hi Sub-zero I am liu kang =)

Comment: Congrats on HNQ.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you are...

> Redundancy

Because the puzzle and hints have a common pattern:

> As [Gareth](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38244393#38244393) pointed out in chat, there are multiple instances of redundant word choice:
>  - "Riddling Riddle"
>  - "absolutely certain"
>  - "positive improvements"
>  - "Each and every one"
>  - "updated and modified"
>  - "Enormously Bigly"
>  - "clues and hints"

And for line 2...

> The temperature notation -40ºC is redundant because -40ºC is also -40ºF; unless you measure temperature in degrees Kelvin, then it would be sufficient to say -40º in casual conversation.
>  (Alternative interpretation: Water freezes when its temperature is decreasing. It begins at a temperature above 0ºC and drops to a temperature below 0ºC. So the water is already ice by the time it has dropped to -40ºC, and it is redundant to specify that it must be frozen.)

Comment: Perfect. Well done! (For line 2, it's your first statement: specifying Celsius is redundant.)

Comment: @TTT But the clues and hints have nothing to do with the answer! True, they do contain a form of it, but that's really too vague!

Comment: @FabioTurati - technically, the actual answer is: I am "Phrases that contain a redundancy." Hint 1 also tells you that you can't solve this riddle like a normal riddle.

Comment: Aw, crap. I had an answer half-written but had somebody stop by my desk. :|  I couldn't think of the term you specified, so mine had said "tautology".

Comment: Tautologies are tautological.

Comment: I accept, approve, endorse, affirm, and authorize this answer.

Comment: Well, I can just say [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/703/)

Answer (score 9):

Are you simply

> **Zero**?

I am absolutely certain of my existence.

> "Absolute zero" or 0K, in keeping with the temperature theme.

My ideal temperature range is between -40ºC and the temperature at which water freezes.

> Water freezes at 0C - if that wasn't directly related to the answer somehow then what would be the purpose of writing it so obliquely?

I can make positive improvements to myself.

> If you go up ("improve") from zero, you reach positive numbers.

What am I?

> Zero.

Title - An Existential Riddle.

> Both nothing (zero) and something at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you are

> Olaf : A snowman built by Elsa Frozen

I am absolutely certain of my existence.

> Olaf is alive, he has concience

My ideal temperature range is between -40ºC and the temperature at which water freezes.

> olaf is a snowman, he live in the very cold place

I can make positive improvements to myself.

> Olaf is by far the friendliest snowman in Arendelle. He is innocent, outgoing and loves all things summer. Olaf may be a bit naive, but his sincerity and good-natured temperament make him a true friend to Anna and Elsa.

Each and every one of you is probably barking up the wrong tree.

> No idea about this

Answer (score 3):

I would guess

> Ice

I am absolutely certain of my existence.

> *Exists* from *Absolute* zero (-273ºC, or 0K)

My ideal temperature range is between -40ºC and the temperature at which water freezes.

> Begins to form when water freezes and continues to expand as a solid until the bonds are completely symmetrical at -40ºC (233K) ([Source](https://www.quora.com/Does-ice-continue-to-expand-below-0-degrees-C))

I can make positive improvements to myself.

> Expands to enlarge itself from 0ºC to -40ºC and improves the symmetry of molecular bonds

With regard to hints:

Each and every one of you is probably barking up the wrong tree.

> Molecular bonds form trees

The title of this puzzle has been updated and modified to be admittedly silly.

> The word "riddling" sounds like some sort of informal synonym or slang for "cold" as in "Brrrr, it's riddling outside!" (clutching at straws here!)

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> The Kelvin temperature scale?

I am absolutely certain of my existence.

> Kelvin is an absolute scale, starting from 0k.

My ideal temperature range is between -40ºC and the temperature at which water freezes.

> Not entirely sure about this one.
>  -40c is the point at which the Celsius and Fahrenheit measurements overlap. -40c = -40f.
>  Water freezes at 0c (273.15K). This is the value which is used to convert K -> C
>  [°C] = [K] − 273.15
>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin

I can make positive improvements to myself.

> Again, Kelvin is an absolute scale, it can only increase; cannot be a negative value

Comment: Not it, but the fact that -40 is the intersection of the C and F scale is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit farfetched, but...

> An ice climber?

I am absolutely certain of my existence

> An ice climber is a person, and people are aware of their own existence

My ideal temperature range is between -40ºC and the temperature at which water freezes.

> When water freezes you have ice, and -40 in Celsius is equal to -40 in Fahrenheit. The objective of the ice climbers is to go up far (Fahr) and (en) reach the maximum height (heit).

I can make positive improvements to myself.

> In the ice climbers video game, you can have a 2nd ice climber with you, which counts for an extra life, hence a positive improvement.

Comment: No, but thanks for the chuckle. The fact that -40 is the intersection of F and C is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly

> Me!

I am absolutely certain of my existence.

> Well, I think, and therefore...

My ideal temperature range is between -40ºC and the temperature at which water freezes.

> I like sledding. Below 40 below, though, that's just too cold.

I can make positive improvements to myself.

> I taught myself to knit!

Answer (score 1):

Most probably a for-fun answer but here goes:

Are you a

> Cool Riddle?

I am absolutely certain of my existence.

> Well, its cool. It knows it exists.

My ideal temperature range is between -40ºC and the temperature at which water freezes.

> So cool that its literally below 0 in temperature?

I can make positive improvements to myself.

> Cool riddles have hints, which are like improvements.

At least it would explain "Each and every one of you is probably barking up the wrong tree."

> Who would guess something so basic and unusual?

The title of this puzzle has been updated and modified to be admittedly silly.

> Is silly the keyword or what? :)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't fit as there is no "knowledge" tag, which would be required for this answer to explain a part of it. But anyway:

> Anyone doing winter sports.

Certain of existence:

> Anyone able to do any sports has enough functioning brain cells to be aware of his/her existence.

Best range between -40 and 0:

> 0 is obvious - ice and snow melts. At around -40C snow stops being slippery.

Some additional explanation for this -40 (you can safely skip it):

> It was observed ages ago that snow behaves kind of like sand instead of being nice for sleds when it is cold enough (= around -35 or 40 or somewhere there). Yet interestingly, to this very day we still do not have a final explanation for this phenomenon. People are taught the completely incorrect "pressure melts ice" bullshit, which does not play a role at all. Currently it is believed there are two dominant contributions. Firstly, there is always a thin layer of water on top of ice (until it gets cold enough it is not energetically favorable anymore), secondly, friction heats up and melts the ice a bit - both producing water on which we slip.

Positive improvements:

> Knowing how ice and snow behave lets us make positive improvements to our equipment, technique etc, achieving better results.

Barking up the wrong tree:

> You need right wood for the best skis, sleds etc (plus a suitable combination with artificial materials)

No idea for the title.